# Clear out some woocommerce cart meta on logout

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have some personal information that I'm building during the checkout process and saving on the cart object.

If the user logs out then I want to leave the product selection in the cart intact, but remove the pii that I've added to the cart.

I've tested this code elsewhere, in a normal template and it clears out the cart:

```
    public function clear_pii_from_cart()
    {
        if (WC()->cart == null) {
            return;
        }

        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
            unset(WC()->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['personalinfo']);
        }

        // save to cart
        WC()->cart->set_session();
    }
```

But when I call it from the `wp_logout` action the info is still in the cart after logout.

I can't figure out how to get any logging into it to be able to see what data structures I'm dealing with.

It just logs out and seems to do nothing.

I know the hook is working because if I put a `die();` in then I get a blank page.

I've combed the WooCommerce source code on github looking for a hint, and not found anything, nor by general searches.

I know this is super niche but does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm, I set the priority of wp_logout to 5 and it suddenly started working.

I was imagining that the session had been destroyed just as I was trying to use it or something like that.